# Как правильно опубликовать python-приложение на хостинге

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, хостинг

Проконсультируйте, пожалуйста, по следующему вопросу.

Пишу бот для телеграма на python. Хочу залить на хостинг, чтобы посмотреть как работает.
У меня есть хостинг (beget), на котором расположен сайт, а точнее мы выкладываем туда внутренние продукты, каждый в своей папке (серверный язык - perl):

```
domen.ru/project1  
domen.ru/project2  
domen.ru/project3
```

и т.д.

Я почитала тех. документацию с их сайта, хостинг так же поддерживает и python (нужно только его установить).

Могу ли я использовать этот хостинг для своего бота для телеграма или лучше выложить на отдельный, чтобы ничего не сломать?

Если можно использовать уже существующий, нужно ли мне создавать новый домен для приложении на python? Или я смогу установить питон на сервер и выложить свое приложение скажем в
domen.ru/projectPy?

Буду рада любым советам!

Comment: Просто установите пайтон и запустите бот. А также запретите доступ к папке с ботом, чтобы не слить токен и иную конфендициальную информацию. Домен иметь не обязательно, нужен только доступ в интернет, а протестировать можно и запустив на своём компьютере. Удачи в работе!

Comment: @GameLinux, благодарю! Буду пробовать.